# Group & Filter organization structure in with dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-analysis

when I organize my analysis as follows:

```
group_by(transactions.DF,MonthCode) %>% 
   filter(str_detect(transactions.DF$Description,"Innocean")) %>% 
   summarize(monthly.income =  sum(Amount))
```

I get the following error:
Error: Result must have length 84, not 3029

when I organize my analysis as follows:

```
transactions.DF %>% 
    filter(str_detect(transactions.DF$Description,"Innocean")) %>% 
    group_by(.$MonthCode) %>% 
    summarize(monthly.income =  sum(Amount))
```

I get my results.

I thought filter would maintain my grouping structure and allow for an analysis

Answer (score 1):

Issue is that using the `transactions.DF$` within the `filter` breaks the grouping and get the values from the entire column instead of the values of the 'Description' with each 'MonthCode'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
transactions.DF %>%
   group_by(MonthCode) %>% 
   filter(str_detect(Description,"Innocean")) %>%
   summarize(monthly.income = sum(Amount))
```

NOTE: The `objectIdentifier$` is not needed within the `tidyverse` functions.  It can be used in certain situations where we are extracting a column from another dataset and doing some comparison

Comment: from the help on filter:
.preserve 
when FALSE (the default), the grouping structure is recalculated based on the resulting data, otherwise it is kept as is.

Comment: @SydV Yes, the grouping structure is maintained if you just use the unquoted column name but here you are breaking the structure by extracting the whole column

Comment: I think you're missing the `$` in your first sentence